# javascript: How to URL encode strings that contain dashes (-)?

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have a string that represents that name of an entity. The name of this entity has a dash in it (-). How can I encode the dash? I believe it should be encoded to '%2D' but when I try encodeURIComponent() or encodeURI() for that matter, it doesn't encode the dash. I was just wondering if there is an encode function that will encode the dash rather than just doing a .replace

Comment: It does not require encoding within a URL, it you want it in % notation you will need tp replace it yourself. (After any other encoding via encode*())

Comment: This can be useful for putting an arbitrary URL into an SVG comment, b/c `--` in the string will terminate the comment and break the SVG. `%2D%2D` in a URL is fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-` is a character that appears in the ASCII character set and has no special meaning in URLs. While you *can* encode it as `%2D`, doing so is not **needed** nor is it **normal**. Encoding it would be like using `%61` instead of `a`.

There is no standard encoding function that will encode a `-` character. `replace` is the logical choice if you really, really want to.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my use case is unique and perhaps hints at a design flaw. But we are replacing spaces with dashes(-) to build URLs pointing at entities. Then when our app routes to one of those urls we replace the dashes in the URL to spaces and fetch the entity. My problem arose when I realized an entity name has a dash already in it. Now I am thinking about if a redesign is necessary in terms of how we are replacing spaces with dashes, etc.