# Redirection to a URL with hyphen doesn't work

Tags: java, web, tomcat, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a simple redirection rule

```
<rule>
    <from>/ask</from>
    <to>https://hlt.com/ask-wisely</to>
</rule>
```

Due to the hyphen being present, the rule doesn't work. If the hyphen doesn't exist, the rule works perfectly fine. It uses the tuckey url-rewrite filter for a java web app.

Comment: perhaps you may need url encoding

Comment: What type of encoding to use ? I used utf-8, it doesnt encode hyphen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503579/javascript-how-to-url-encode-strings-that-contain-dashes